# Rewrite subdomain to www counterpart

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect http://sub.domain.com to http://www.sub.domain.com but also have http://domain.com redirect to http://www.domain.com.

This is what I have for the domain part

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How hard is this to do?

Comment: Here is the solution: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: please add the comment as an answer. It seems to be correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)| 
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```